# Form validation isn't actually returning false for one input field of the whole form

Tags: javascript, regex, html, validation

So I'm working on a form validation project. We're given a set of criteria that our inputs must meet, and we've got to use regular expressions to check everything. I've got everything coded out, and everything works perfectly except for the first input. It checks against the regular expression, but if there's anything wrong with the match, it will return true instead of false, and bring the window to the "form accepted" page.

```
function validate_registration(){
    var RegExpName = /^[A-Z a-z]+$/;
    var RegExpCourseId = /^WEB*([1-9]{1})*[0-9]{2}$/;

    var studentName = document.reg_page.student_name.value;
    var courseID = document.reg_page.course_id.value;

    if (!RegExpName.test(studentName))
    {
        alert("Please enter the name on your Student ID");
        document.reg_page.s.focus();
        document.reg_page.s.select();
        return false;
    }

    else if (!RegExpCourseId.test(courseID))
    {
        alert("Please enter a valid Course ID");
        document.reg_page.c.focus();
        document.reg_page.c.select();
        return false;
    }
}

<div id="container">
<div id="page">
    <form name="reg_page" method="post" onSubmit="return validate_registration();"   action="thanks.htm" >
    <table id="form">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><div id="table_title">Web Registration Form</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Student Name:</td><td><input name="student_name" id="s" size="15" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Course ID:</td><td><input name="course_id" id="c" size="10" /></td>
        </tr>
```

That's the pertinent bits of the javascript and the form. The Course ID area works perfectly. If it's blank, it returns false, and highlights the text input field. Why won't it do the same with Student Name?

Comment: If this is your actual code and you didn't make a copy-paste error, you are missing a closing bracket for your function.

Comment: This isn't my actual code. Just copy and pasted the first half of the function and the form, since that's where the issue lies.

Comment: Where are you seeing the problem? This seems to work correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/k4mWw/1/

Comment: @Shmiddty Where is it. Can't find!

Comment: @PraveenKumar I edited the code for formatting, and put the closing bracket in. It was a `}` to close the main function you have

Comment: ianpgall, when I load the actual page, and leave the first field blank, the alert pops up telling me there's an error. Then, when I return back to the form, instead of highlighting the field, it just goes straight through to "thanks.htm".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not having any problems with that. I had to add a submit button and I obviously don't have the thanks.htm page, but here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BmLYD/3/. Have I done anything different than what you're trying/where exactly you're placing your code?

Answer (score 1):

Not truly an answer per se but since SO doesn't let me comment till I have 50 rep, this is what I have to work with.

Anyway, your code works fine for me in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BBtPP/4/) on Chromium on Linux. Could you post information about your target system? What browser and OS are you on? Also could you clarify what should and shouldn't pass your validation. I tried following the regex (I'm not all that experienced with regex) and it looks like it passes everything it should, which in this case seems to be anything without numbers or symbols.

Another thing you could try is posting your console log after you attempt to use the script to see if maybe that has some useful information as to where the issue actually is.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the whole code?!

This code works for me (FireFox):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function validate_registration(){
var RegExpName = /^[A-Z a-z]+$/;
var RegExpCourseId = /^WEB*([1-9]{1})*[0-9]{2}$/;

var studentName = document.reg_page.student_name.value;
var courseID = document.reg_page.course_id.value;

if (!RegExpName.test(studentName))
    {
        alert("Please enter the name on your Student ID");
        document.reg_page.s.focus();
        document.reg_page.s.select();
        return false;
    }

else if (!RegExpCourseId.test(courseID))
    {
        alert("Please enter a valid Course ID");
        document.reg_page.c.focus();
        document.reg_page.c.select();
        return false;
    }
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <form name="reg_page" method="post" onSubmit="return validate_registration();">
    <table id="form">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><div id="table_title">Web Registration Form</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Student Name:</td><td><input name="student_name" id="s" size="15" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Course ID:</td><td><input name="course_id" id="c" size="10" /></td>
        </tr>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
     </table>
     </form>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Did you probably just forget to close the function?

Comment: The function is indeed closed. I just copied half of it, since the other half isn't having the issue, and forgot to close it in the post. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps checkout the jQuery validation plugin if using jQuery is an option?
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend just using two if statements instead of an else if statement, see what that does.